# How to position a SVG image(which its path has negative values) onto Google Map correctly

Tags: html, css, google-maps, svg

I need to draw SVG pictures onto Google Map. The problem is:

A. The SVG path has negative values, so if I don't shift these pictures, they will look like a quarter of themselves. e.g.
(Here is the airplane only gets a quarter of its own displayed)

[image: a quarter of the airplane its own]

B. But if I shift it(by using padding-left, padding-top on the SVG element and I have a div wrapper, but if I add these style on the div, then it doesn't work), the displayed aircraft gets deviated from its track. It should be displayed right on the top of the green circled point, instead it is positioned below its correct position.

And to give you a more straightforward view of my problem, here is the html code

```
   <div class="aircraft">
    <svg version="1.1" style="padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px;"
         width="10px" height="10px" >
        <path fill="blue" stroke-width="3" 
              d="m 1 2 3" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

**So the question is:**

How to display full svg images which their paths have negative values and position them correctly without being deviated.

Thank you.

---

**Update**

I saw one of the answers uses viewBox="-8.1 -7.6 50 50" and it solves the problem!
But just wondering how did you calculate to get the values(both min-x,min-y and width,height in viewBox) of viewBox and make it display correctly?

Because I will need to calculate the values of viewBox for each one of my many svg iamges

---

**Update 2**

Here is the code which tries to set correct value for viewBox of the svg, but it doesn't work.
Here is the linke  ->  http://jsfiddle.net/MNP6P/4/

Html:

```
<pre id="out">
</pre>

<svg version="1.1" width="100px" height="100px">
  <path d="m 1 2 3" id="6"/>

</svg>
```

Javascript:

```
var  paths = document.querySelectorAll('svg path');
var  lines = [];
var bbox;
for (var i=0; i<paths.length; i++) {
    bbox = paths[i].getBBox();
    lines.push(bbox.x+" "+bbox.y+" "+bbox.width+" "+bbox.height );    
}

$('svg').attr("viewBox", lines[0]);


document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = lines.join("\n");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a suitable `viewBox` to your svg:

```
<svg version="1.1" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="-8.6 -7.1 16 14">
    <path fill="blue" stroke-width="3"
          d="m 1.4407594,6.9494512 -3,-6 -4,0 -2,0 -1,-1 1,-1 2,0 4,0 3,-6
             1,0 0,6 3,0 2,-3 0,8 0,0 -2,-3 -3,0 0,6 -1,0" />
</svg>
```

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/MNP6P/)

Now the contents of your SVG will be scaled and centred in the area specified by the SVG width and height.  All you need to do then is to position the SVG so that it's centre is where you want the plane to be.  So for SVG `width="10px" height="10px"` absolutely position the SVG at (planeX - 5, planeY - 5) etc.

Comment: Thank you for the help :) it seems that viewBox is the magician. But I just can't find a good tutorial explaining me why you have -8.6 and -7.1 as its min-x and min-y. And how did you get these result to make my SVG display correctly(quite interested in here)? I have several svg images, so I have to get the right viewBox values for each one of them. Could you please explain it to me? thank you very much.

Comment: Hi BigBadaboom, thank you for your help, please see my updated post.

Comment: To get the viewBox I used a getBBox() call on the path element.  See http://jsfiddle.net/MNP6P/2/  Also note that your path definition is using relative path commands.  So that might be why you are surprised that the viewBox has coords that don't appear like they belong.  But if you look at the X coord of the first five path command coord pairs you get: 1.4 - 3 - 4 - 2 - 1 = -8.6.

Comment: This may help. I converted your iconDefs to paths and wrote a bit of Javascript to print out all your bboxes. http://jsfiddle.net/MNP6P/3/

Comment: hi there, thank you very much for your detailed reply. I expressed in a wrong way. I actually want to know how you calculate to get the -8.6 and -7.1 and 16 and 14? I saw the answer from your second comment. Now I wonder why you only choose the first FIVE path coord pairs? why not 6,7 8 ...etc.? Is there a formula to follow so I can use to calculate whatever path I have? That will be the key for understanding the concept of svg path. thank you.

Comment: The bounding box describes the lower and upper limits in both the X and Y direction.  The reason it was five coords is just because that was as far left as the X coords went. And it showed where the -8.6 came from.

Comment: hi BigBadaboom, inside the d attribute there are 19 pairs of coords, so there are 19 X coords went and I also checked the rest of other 14 Xs, some are greater/smaller then the first 5 X coords. So I still haven't understood how the number 5(the number of X coords that need to be taken into account) come. Thank you.

Comment: hi there, I updated your code and added dynamical calculation of bbox to svg and I was expecting the aircraft can be displayed correct, however only its quarter is displayed(same as not adding the viewBox). Here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MNP6P/4/

Comment: You can't use jQuery's methods reliably to manipulate SVG elements. It is designed to work in the HTML namespace, not the SVG one.  Use the DOM's `setAttribute()` method instead.  http://jsfiddle.net/MNP6P/5/

Comment: Lower case path commands are *relative*.  So you have to accumulate the sum.  1.4 -3 (=-1.6) -4 (=-5.6) - 2 (=-7.6) - 1 (=-8.6). After that the relative X coords are positive so the absolute value (sum) increases (-8.6 +1 (=-7.6) etc).  -8.6 is the lowest absolute X coord in the path.

Comment: oooooo~! So can I assume that for each of different paths, I have to go through all X coords to see when I get the lowest value in order to get the min-x and it's same for min-y? Also, how did you calculate to get the x and y (in this case they are 16 and 14)?

Comment: Those are width and height. So keep track of maxX and maxY as well and subtract minX/minY from them at the end.

Comment: If you haven't already, read the viewBox section in the SVG spec. http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute

Comment: okay, so that means go through all X/Y coords to find out minX minY and maxX and maxY and width = maxX- minX; height = maxY - minY. I must be correct this time :) thank you